# Best practice (effiency) data manipulation of pandas big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, data-manipulation

I'm dealing with a large datasets and I would like to ask the best way to change some entries of a pandas data frame `df`

Here is my code:

```
mask = df.P2I.values > c_th
df.loc[mask, 'P1I'] = df.P1I - c_offset
df.loc[mask, 'P3I'] = df.P3I - c_offset
df.loc[mask, 'P2I'] = df.P2I - c_offset
```

1. Is there a way to access those rows-columns directly in a single call and do three operations altogether?
2. Should I call `.values` to the data frame to have a continuous memory allocation to do the subtraction?

I can't measure performance that's why I'm asking. Thanks guys

Comment: Can i ask why you are unable to measure performance? I think just trying it out will be the best solution! :)

Comment: I'm still studying how to do it properly while using python scripts

Comment: If you can’t measure performance then why are you looking for ways to optimize the program?

Comment: It takes long to compute so I'm learning how to optimize small pieces of code and best practices to improve the codebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in your case:

```
df.loc[mask, ['P1I', 'P2I', 'P3I']] -= c_offset
```

You can also use different offsets for each column if you need to, like this (in terms of performance it looks to be rather similar to the first one):

```
df.loc[mask, ['P1I', 'P2I', 'P3I']] -= [ c_offset_1, c_offset_2, c_offset_3 ]
```

However, if performance is crucial, it seems like the best options is indeed use the numpy format. Probably if your "mathematical wrangling" is larger than a single subtraction, this seems the way to go:

```
df.loc[ mask, ["P1I", "P2I", "P3I"]] = df.loc[ mask, ["P1I", "P2I", "P3I"]].values - c_offset
```

*Note*: OP tested this approach in his/her dataset, and mentioned that it was actually slower than just using the previous one. Tried to replicate this, but my computer almost crashed before I was able to...

Some timings I took comparing the different approaches:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ "P1I": np.random.rand(1000000), 
                    "P2I": np.random.rand(1000000), 
                    "P3I": np.random.rand(1000000) })

c_th = 0.5
c_offset = -1

mask = df.P2I > c_th
%timeit df.loc[ mask, "P1I" ] = df.loc[ mask , "P1I" ] - c_offset; df.loc[ mask, "P2I" ] = df.loc[ mask , "P2I" ] - c_offset; df.loc[ mask, "P3I" ] = df.loc[ mask , "P3I" ] - c_offset
# 77.9 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[ mask, ["P1I", "P2I", "P3I"]] -= c_offset
# 59.3 ms ± 1.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[ mask, ["P1I", "P2I", "P3I"]] -= [ c_offset, c_offset, c_offset ]
# 59.5 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[ mask, ["P1I", "P2I", "P3I"]] = df.loc[ mask, ["P1I", "P2I", "P3I"]].values - c_offset
# 43.6 ms ± 553 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your testing, my results are different with larger datasets. Numpy conversion is slower than doing it with pandas. I guess it's due to the memory allocation being slower compared to the advantage of the operation in a continous memory space.

Comment: The results with dataframe of size 63757792 is that df.loc[mask_c_offset, ['P1I', 'P2I', 'P3I']] -= c_offset is way faster than df.loc[mask_c_offset, ['P1I', 'P2I', 'P3I']].values-c_offset